# Splitting by more than one delimiter C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I am trying to split sentences apart by punctuation (`.`, `?`, `!`). I have found on StackOverflow a way to separate a string by one delimiter, but I have not been able to find a way to separate a string based on multiple delimiters at once. Here is the code I have so far:

```cpp
void chopSentences(std::string new_sentences, std::vector<std::string> sentences) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    std::string delimiter = ".";
    while ((pos = new_sentences.find(delimiter) != std::string::npos)) {
        token = new_sentences.substr(0, pos);
        sentences.push_back(token);
        new_sentences.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to make it more than one delimiter?

Comment: You can use [strtok](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), which is a `c` function, but it gets the job done.

Comment: [`std::basic_string::find_first_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Comment: Note:  the `strtok` function modifies the string that is searched.

Comment: You are making unneeded copies of your original string in `new_sentences.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());`. I would instead save the previous `pos` and search from it, then use both previos and current `pos` in a call to `substr`.

Comment: Is using Boost's Tokenizer or algorithm::split an option?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++11 or later, you can use `std::regex_iterator`:

```cpp
std::string const s{"Hello, Johnny! Are you there?"};`
 
std::regex words_regex("[^[:punct:]\\?]+");
auto words_begin = 
    std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), words_regex);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
 
std::cout << "Found " 
          << std::distance(words_begin, words_end) 
          << " words:\n";
 
for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    std::smatch match = *i;                                                 
    std::string match_str = match.str(); 
    std::cout << match_str << '\n';
}
```

And then the printout is:

```
Found 3 words:
Hello
 Johnny
  Are you there
```

You'll have to further adjust the regex to remove the whitespace.